# Retrieve list of ports in a map to create a security group resource

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have an merged maps as a variable like this :

`variable "ep" {`

`type = map(`

`object(`

`{ name = string`

`port = list(string)`

`}   ))}`

I need to map this to create a security group

```
\`resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {

 for_each = var.ep

 description = "good desc - $each.key"

 type = "ingress"

 from_port = try(each.value.port,443)

 to_port = try(each.value.port,443)

 protocol = "abc"

}\`
```

This throws an error that list is being read. What should be the way to map each and every port on the list into the security group rule?

TIA

I tried creating dynamic blocks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to map the port list to `from_port` and `to_port`, but they accept a single integer, not a list.

You must flatten the map and use `for_each`, where each object has a single port.

```
locals {
  flat_ep = flatten([
    for k, v in var.ep : [
      for port in v.port : {
        key  = k
        name = v.name
        port = port
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  for_each = {for x in local.flat_ep : "${x.key}-${x.port}" => x}

  description = "good desc - ${each.value.key}"
  type        = "ingress"
  from_port   = tonumber(each.value.port)
  to_port     = tonumber(each.value.port)
  protocol    = "TCP"
}
```